# Why does strip not remove the leading whitespace?

Tags: ruby, strip, ruby-2.0

I tried to `strip` the leading whitespace of a string:

```
" Bagsværd".strip # => " Bagsværd"
```

I expect it to return `"Bagsværd"` instead.

Comment: That's odd. I'm running Ruby 2.0.0p247 and Rails 4.0.0, and " Bagsværd".strip returns "Bagsværd" for me. The same happens in Ruby 1.9.3p484 with Rails 3.2.13. Have you tried this in another version of Ruby or Rails?

Comment: `strip` removes leading whitespace on every interpreter I've seen, do you get the same result when pasting this into a fresh IRB console?

Comment: No. I have also just upgraded to 2.0.0p353 due to security issues with p272 (which I was using earlier). And yes, I have reloaded the console many times, but still get the above output.

Comment: maybe something wrong with your locale settings?

Comment: What could that be for instance?

Comment: Downvoter state reason?

Comment: Why is this post getting downvotes?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Where did the string `" Bagsværd"` come from?

It’s likely that the space character at the start of the string is not a “normal” space, but a non-breaking space (U+00A0):

```
2.0.0p353 :001 > " Bagsværd".strip
 => "Bagsværd" 
2.0.0p353 :002 > "\u00a0Bagsværd".strip
 => " Bagsværd"
```

You could remove it with [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) rather than `strip`:

```
2.0.0p353 :003 > "\u00a0Bagsværd".gsub(/\A\p{Space}*/, '')
 => "Bagsværd"
```

This uses the [`\A` anchor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors), and the [`\p{Space}` character property](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties) to emulate `lstrip`. To strip both leading and trailing whitespace, use:

```
2.0.0p353 :007 > "\u00a0Bagsværd\u00a0".gsub(/\A\p{Space}*|\p{Space}*\z/, '')
 => "Bagsværd"
```

Comment: +1 for using the `\p{Space}`. An alternate is to use the Posix `[[:space:]]` character set: `" Bagsværd"[/[[:space:]]/] # => "\u00A0"`.

Comment: the take-away here is A> string surgery vs UTF-8 (or -16 etc) sucks, per http://mortoray.com/2013/11/27/the-string-type-is-broken/ , and B> if your string surgery fails, barf out `" Bagsværd".bytes` to see if the leading space really is a `32`!

Comment: Is this a bug in strip() implementation or not? Documentation say "Returns a copy of str with leading and trailing whitespace removed". No-break space is a whitespace, isn't it?

Comment: Well, it seems like a bug -- bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7845

Comment: @shau-kote not a bug as such, as it is the intended behaviour, mainly (I think) to avoid affecting existing code using the string methods. But from the comments in that thread this may change in a future version.

Comment: If you want to laugh a little bit and also learn more about "the white space" check this blog post! :-) http://heavydots.com/blog/when-the-white-space-became-a-beast There's both a story and some tools/techniques to deal with it.. mostly from the PHP realm.. but can be interpreted and translated to Rails :-D

Comment: Wow, thanks, was just having this issue when trying to strip leading whitespace on an import from csv

Answer (score 4):

The first character in your string is *not* whitespace

```
" Bagsværd".bytes
[194, 160, 66, 97, 103, 115, 118, 195, 166, 114, 100]

" Bagsværd".chars[0].ord
 => 160
```

This is `U+00A0` no-break space. Note I could tell this because the editable form of the question preserves the character (whilst anyone trying to cut and paste from the *rendered* SO post would not be able to replicate your problem)

Comment: Hence "new-f***s can't tri-force" C-;

Answer (score 3):

The most likely way that `strip` isn't removing a space, is when it isn't really a space, but is a non-breaking space.

Try this on your machine:

```
# encoding: utf-8
" Bagsværd".chars.map(&:ord)
```

On mine, using Ruby 2.0.0p353:

```
# => [160, 66, 97, 103, 115, 118, 230, 114, 100]
```

Comment: Actually if you edit the OP, you get his original string with the non-breaking space. Whilst cut&paste from the rendered post and SO has converted it to a regular space.

Comment: Yeah, I just did that and, sure 'nough, there it was.

Answer (score 0):

Is the first character a space or something else, e.g. \u00af ([Non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space))

This could give the same result:

```
#encoding: utf-8
puts " Bagsværd".strip #Bagsværd
a = "\u00A0Bagsværd"
puts a         # Bagsværd
puts a.strip  # Bagsværd

#Maybe the example works not, when the code is posted/taken via cut+paste
b = ' Bagsværd'
p a == b  #true
```

You can check what you have with:

```
a = "\u00A0Bagsværd"
b = ' Bagsværd'
p a.codepoints.to_a #[160, 66, 97, 103, 115, 118, 230, 114, 100]
p b.codepoints.to_a #[32, 66, 97, 103, 115, 118, 230, 114, 100]
```